# Metaspace grows over time java 8

Tags: java-8

[image]

While going through the heap dump - seeing duplicate java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm class instance. Please find attached.

Comment: Are you reloading code?

Comment: @Stephen - i didn't get you. How can i verify that?

Comment: You don't "verify" it.  Are you running Tomcat or WebSphere or something, and updating your application without doing a full restart?

Comment: Having more than one instance of a class is normal for most classes. What makes you think that, e.g. having 36 instances of `java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH`, is a problem? Or do you fail to recognize that `java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH`, `java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH`, and `java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH` are three different classes? And what is “Please find attached” supposed to mean?